# web.config URL access and rewrite

Tags: iis, iis-7, rewrite

I'm trying to clean up some URLs to a bunch of PDF files. Right now, you access a PDF by visiting the following:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/sites/default/files/reports/2010_Audit_Summary_Report.pdf`

But I want to clean this up by being able to access the same files using this URL:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/reports/2010_Audit_Summary_Report.pdf`

I thought that I might be able to do the following:

```
<rule name="MySpecialRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/sites/default/files/reports/2010_Audit_Summary_Report.pdf" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/reports/2010_Audit_Summary_Report.pdf" />
</rule>
```

But this is not working. Of course, the sample rule above would only work for one PDF, where I want this to work for all PDFs within the same directory.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not really understanding why no one has a solution ... I know this is possible, I just don't exactly know how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

To match more than one specific URL, you need to use a regular expression and then reference the found string in the action:

```
 <rule name="MySpecialRule" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="/sites/default/files/reports/([_a-z0-9]+).pdf" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/reports/{R:1}.pdf" />
 </rule>
```

Here I assume your filename consists only of letters, digits and underscores. I haven't tested this, but it should give you the idea how to solve this.

Comment: Peter, thanks so much for taking the time to answer! I'll test this out and get back to you.